# ipywdigets layout: How to control the spacing between widgets in a vertical or horizontal box

Tags: python

I'm hoping to get some help in understanding how to control the spacing between widgets in either a vertical or horizontal box?

I'm asking because I'd like to reduce the spacing of HBox: `logX_LogYCheckBoxContainer`.To me the spacing between `Log X` and `Log Y` check boxes in the image below seems excessive. Ideally, I'd like to reduce it.

I've checked the Ipywidgets website, but couldn't find anything. Hopefully someone here knows the answer.

Thank you!

[image]